# Error while installing react using the "npx create-react-app my-app" command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am a beginner and was trying to install react and an error came up,
telling me that there are two similar files and it cant decide which one to use:

[image]

I deleted the "my-app" folder (not from terminal) and tried to reinstall so that it would work , but instead another error came up, probably because the folder wasnt correctly deleted:

[image]

Can somebody tell me what to do to make React work?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Remove package.json and try again